# Issue : Convering XML to Dataset - Bullet Symbol Converts to Question Mark...?

Tags: c#, xml

**Part of  C# code :**
This is the Code that is reading XML and Convert this to DataSET.

```
  *byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response); .. (1)
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.ReadXml(stream);
  return ds;*
```

**response:**
This is the response used by statement (1),XML part

```
 *<summary>

  ● Brand
  ● Strategic
  ● Generated
  ● Comprehensive
 </summary>*
```

***Result:***
Now When Value is assigned to Data set,

```
     *● is converted to "?" while converting to C#*
```

Comment: are you shure that your response in ASCII?

Comment: Yes.i am sure.The code is exactly same as in "Part of code Section",
here i am not able to understand why Bullet sign is updated to "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII doesn't contain bullet.

Your XML probably in UTF-8 encoding. If it is, use this code:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
```

You may check encoding of your xml in a first row of xml